# can someone confirm my understanding of this if statement is correct

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm learning javascript and want to make sure i understand what is happening here.

Is the 'if' part of the statement in my code saying "string" (as in the type of data it is) == "images/card_back.jpg" therefore returns false.

It also returns false if i change == "images/card_back.jpg" to == "string". Is this because although the type of data is "string" it's not the same thing because it's essentially saying data type "string" is the same as the characters "string".

Also is the 'if else' part of the statement using the match() function to find "card" within the "images/card_back.jpg" source character string therefore returns true as card is in that string.

```js
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = typeof document.getElementById("myImage").src;

if (document.getElementById("myImage").src == "images/card_back.jpg"){
document.getElementById("output 1").innerHTML = "output 1 working"
} else if(document.getElementById("myImage").src.match("card")){
document.getElementById("output 2").innerHTML = "output 2 working"
}else {
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<p id="test"></p>

<p id="output 1"></p>
<p id="output 2"></p>


<img id="myImage" src="images/card_back.jpg" width="80" height="80">


</body>
</html>
```

I was going to attach an image saved on my computer showing what the code outputs but not sure how to do this here.

The code outputs:

string

output 2 working

(an image of the back of a card)

Comment: you can't have spaces in your ID. right now you have duplicated ids `output`..

Comment: if you're doing `==` comparison, it's comparing the actual values.  If you need to check a data type, use `typeof`.  Instead of `match`, `includes` might be more appropriate for your purposes.  But ultimately, it's really hard to understand what you're asking here, so my comments are just shots in the dark re: a "solution."

Comment: There's no `if` statement dealing with types here. `typeof` returns a string, so it would act as a string if you were using it in a comparison anywhere, which you're not. I'm not really sure *what* you're asking. You're comparing an image `src` attribute with a JPG filename, and you say the string `"string"`--if the `src` attribute isn't that, it'll return false.

Comment: The computed `src` *property* will include `http://example.com/pathToCurrentPage/`. Use `getAttribute('src')` for the abbreviated version in the html

Comment: @Stender _"you can't have spaces in your ID. right now you have duplicated ids output"_. Though having spaces is `id` will have some problems. But it doesnot mean `<p id="output 1"></p>` have two ids `output` and `1`

Comment: @MaheerAli I see your are right, that most browsers will act as if the whitespace is part of the ID - Still, the guideline should be `Do not have spaces in your IDs`

Comment: @Stender Yes obviously there shouldn't be. I couldn't think you of a way to use ids containing whitespace in css selector.

Comment: **USE DEBUGG  ! ( F12 + console.log )**

Comment: I have just removed 'type of' and see that it now outputs the full path of the image instead of 'string', so i understand what is happening now. I'm not really sure why i thought to put 'type of' in the first place now. I copy/pasted the full path in place of == "images/card_back.jpg" and it returns true as i'd now expect. I'm not planning to use the full path in future of course but just wanted to make sure i understood what is happening.